# Contact Role Required on Opportunity Upon Creation

Tags: validation-rule, opportunity, record, sales

I want to have contact roles required when an opportunity is created or even marked as stage 1. However, I only want to use this on my renewal opportunity record type and not the others. How would I set up the validation rule for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with a validation rule because `OpportunityContactRole` (`OCR` for short) is a *child* of the `Opportunity` SObject. i.e. there can be more than 1 OCR on any given `Opportunity`. Validation rules can only reference data upwards in a hierarchy (from parent -> grandparent, up to 5 levels "up"), we can't go down (from parent -> child).

Even if you could do it though, you would not want to do it because parents (i.e. the Opportunity) needs to be inserted before any child records (OCRs) could be related to it. The `ISNEW()` function isn't reliable (or at least, it's never been for me) if you have any other automation that happens (workflow, process builder, flows, approval processes, etc...).

We also can't have a rollup summary field to count OCRs, though that would be something that the DLRS tool, a flow, or a trigger would be able to help with.

In the end, you can't really get away from allowing the Opportunity to be created without this restriction. You'll need to:

- Allow the Opp to be created
- Use some other method to detect/count OCR records related to the Opp (and store that data on the Opp)
- Create a validation rule for some later `StageName` (or perhaps some other field)

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense as to why it would not work. Would you recommend creating a field on the Opportunity for Primary Contact? Or other recommendations? I thought the relationship between Opportunity and OCR was a lookup relationship and not a master detail, however I could be wrong

Comment: @M.M.19 Without more information, my recommendation is the final 3 bullet points of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [Non Profit Success Pack](https://www.salesforce.org/products/nonprofit-success-pack/) implements this by doing that you suggested - create a lookup to Contact that is required, and then build automation to set the Primary OCR - Lookup, and also remove\add if the Lookup value is changed. Now that there are triggers on OCR, it is also easier to enforce the data consistency.
But obviously this requires more code\flow than just having some validation rule based on the Stage etc. - so depends on how critical it is to enter a Contact on create